# Realm where clause returns 0 even if data is present in realmDB

Tags: android, realm

Im using where clause in IntentService in android ,If I use the where clause the first 7 or 8 times it gives me the desired output but after certain time it fails and gives 0 for the result

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance().getRealmConfig(Constants.SCHEMA_LIVE));
            RealmResults<RContactDTO> localContacts = realm.where(RContactDTO.class).equalTo("operationType", HttpOperation.PUT.name()).findAll();
            Utils.Log("update contact count ::: " + localContacts.size(), Utils.LogType.DEBUG);
            ArrayList<ContactDTO> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactDTO>();
            RContactDTO rContactDTO = null;
            for(RContactDTO rContact : localContacts){
                contactList.add(new ContactDTO(rContact));
            }
```

I have checked the actual data by exporting the realmDB.

Comment: So you run the same code 9 times, it works 8 times and doesn't work the 9th?

Comment: yes after 9th time it works randomly which is unpredictable

Comment: And there is nothing happening in between tries?

Comment: It works fine when i run a fresh app but fails after some time

Comment: is it possible items have been deleted during "some time"?

Comment: no item is present to check that i exported the realmDB the data was present but still the query returned 0

Comment: Is there any other way to extract data from realm other than the where clause

Comment: You can get the default.realm(or *.realm) file from the phone and check it in an editor.

Comment: Is the data written in another thread? May be it is not up-to-date at that point? Consider to use https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

Comment: @beeender thanks for the reply but i got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in Swift. Realm have some issue with auto refresh.

Use 
realm.refresh()  before doing your clause.

Comment: Wait, what? Realm-Java deprecated `refresh()` in 0.90.0, and removed it in 1.0.0. This is not a solution. Auto-refresh works just fine on looper threads that actually loop; and non-looper threads are meant to use `waitForChange()` to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

In an IntentService, you're on a looper thread that doesn't loop. So that means your Realm cannot auto-update on an IntentService's thread, and it can't wait for changes either. So the workaround is to either use a normal thread and use `waitForChange()` instead of an IntentService, or close the Realm when you no longer need it for an operation and then re-open it with `getDefaultInstance()`.